# Nodes count always zero when checked using capability API

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

When I try to share data between android wear emulator(app installed : wear module) and android device (app installed : mobile module), I am checking the number of nodes set using capabilityAPI before sending a message and the result always seem to be 0. My device and wear emulator are always connected.In fact, I am able to send notification from device to wear emulator.Below is the code (obviously called inside a service function),

```
  GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();

    ConnectionResult connectionResult = googleApiClient.blockingConnect(
            Constants.GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_TIMEOUT_S, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    if (connectionResult.isSuccess() && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult result = Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability(
                googleApiClient,
                "SHOW DETAILS",
                CapabilityApi.FILTER_REACHABLE)
                .await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Set<Node> nodes = result.getCapability().getNodes();
            for (Node node : nodes) {
                Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                        googleApiClient, node.getId(), path, extraInfo.getBytes());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "startDeviceActivityInternal() Failed to get capabilities, status: "
                    + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
        }

        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
```

Do suggest.

Note: My both modules package name are same.Also , any clarification on how capability name works would be great.